# highstock with google finance api

Tags: javascript, highcharts, google-finance

i try to make a stockchart using Google Finance API.

I'm using the demo like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/)

I've try to change the link from

```
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function (data)
```

to use google finance API

```
$.getJSON('https://www.google.com/finance/historical?output=csv&q=LQ45', function (data)
```

but still doesn't work, maybe I have to parsing the data first ? can anyone tell me how ? thanks

Comment: does `https://www.google.com/finance/historical?output=csv&q=LQ45` returns you something ?  I got 400 error !

Comment: Link provided by you, does not return anything, page does not exist.

Comment: @RahulNaik the link is working fine with me, the link give me a csv file.

Comment: @TakdirSaputro to make that thing work you need to feed data in the same format as `https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?` returns

Comment: thank you, have done that already. now my system is working